# xsl:calltemplate with name supplied by a parameter

Tags: xslt

I would like to call a template based on an inbound parameter to an xsl stylesheet.

Using the parameter in the name attribute fails because $ is illegal in the context.  Does this mean I have to use a xsl:choose to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I mean in XPath 2.0 you could use the inline "if" to select between user-defined functions, but that only applies in limited situations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call templates selected dynamically then you can usually do it using xsl:apply-templates rather than xsl:call-template. One very general way of doing this is to change each

```
<xsl:template name="n">
```

to

```
<xsl:template name="n" match="xsl:template[@name='n']">
```

and then change your invalid

```
<xsl:call-template name="$x"/>
```

to a legitimate

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/xsl:template[@name=$x]">
```

And pass the context item as a parameter if necessary.

However, if we knew more about the problem you are trying to solve, we might be able to suggest a better way of solving it.

Comment: I'm trying to keep all the forms in template libraries and then based on what was requested output a specific form without having to update the choose each time a new supported form is added.  Even though this works, it seems a bit difficult for "the next guy" to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use an XSLT processor like the commercial version of Saxon 9 where you have an extension instruction like http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/instructions/call-template.xml you will need to use xsl:choose.