# Call xsl template with a name that is coming from xml (page source)

Tags: xml, xslt

How do I call an xsl template (`<xsl:call-template name="myPage">`)?

Where 'myPage' is a dynamic name which will vary based on the xml output of any give page. In other words, with page source as follows:

```
<html>
<page> pageName  </page>   
</html>
```

I need to `<xsl:call-template name="pageName">`.

Comment: Head on over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473659/xslcalltemplate-with-name-supplied-by-a-parameter and see that answers your needs...

Comment: Also see [How to call named templates based on a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1233702/290085)

Comment: Do you have some example code?

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic despatch mechanism in XSLT is `xsl:apply-templates`. You could for example have a set of template rules of the form

```
<xsl:template match="page[. = 'pageName']"/>
<xsl:template match="page[. = 'someOtherName']"/>
etc
```

and then call

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/html/page"/>
```

You'll probably want to pass the context item as well, which you can do as a parameter using xsl:with-param.

Comment: Where do 'pageName' and 'someOtherName' come from? In other words, how do I pull them in from xml. If it helps, I can play around with the xml code, adding id's and the like as needed. Different pages can have their own xml output, what I really need is one single call-template which can call different templates based on the xml. (Like I said, I can do whatever is needed in the xml code itself.

Comment: And as I said, if you want dynamic despatch you should look to apply-templates rather than call-template.